# Can ($X^I$, product topology) and ($X^I$, box topology) be homeomorphic for some nontrivial $X$ and infinite $I$?

Tags: general-topology, product-space, box-topology

Let $X$ be a nontrivial topological space, $I$ be a infinite set, we can endow $X^I$ (the set of all functions $I\to X$) with either the product topology or the box topology. We know that the box topology is strictly finer than product topology, but since a topology can be homeomorphic to a strictly finer topology, can the product topology be homeomorphic to the box topology anyway?

Comment: This seems unlikely.  If $x\in X$ is a non-isolated point of $X$ and $\kappa$ is the minimum possible cardinality for a neighborhood base at $x$, then the point $(x,x,\ldots)$ has a neighborhood base of cardinality $\kappa\cdot |I|$ under the product topology, but the cardinality of the smallest neighborhood base for this point in the box topology should be something like $\kappa^{|I|}$.

Comment: Well, for $X$ antidiscrete the topologies coincide, no?

Comment: @freakish I said nontrivial in the first sentence :)

Comment: [mathoverflow.se]: [Can ($X^I$, product topology) and ($X^I$, box topology) be homeomorphic for some nontrivial $X$ and infinite $I$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/431630)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you all for your work!